# FreeMarker check the class name of an object

Tags: freemarker

is there a way to get the class name of an object in a freemarker template ?

For instance:

```
<#if component.javaType.class.name.equals("test")  > 
 "something...."
</#else>
 "something else ...."
</#if>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no feature built in for that, but depending on the configuration settings and on the type of the object, this may works:

```
<#if component.class.name == 'com.example.Something'>
```

That works because `component.foo` simply means `comonent.getFoo()` in Java, so the above just means `component.getClass().getName()`. This, however doesn't work if the JavaBean properties of `component` aren't exposed, which (assuming the usual FreeMarker configuration) is the case for `String`-s, `Number`-s, `Map`-s, `List`-s and some more "standard" classes. If `component` can be a such object, but the comparison should be false for them anyway, you can write `(component.class.name)!'unknown' == 'com.example.Something'`.

Comment: I uset  <#if component.class.name?contains("TextComponentModel")> is useful so i avoid to specify the full class name.

Comment: `?endsWith(".TextComponentModel")` (or `ends_with`) would be safer than `?contains("TextComponentModel")`.

Comment: Thanks, sure it is.

Comment: @fustaki True. Perhaps the best is to write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` for this...

Comment: You can use <#if component.class.simpleName == 'Something'> to get the short name of the class. This should also help with inheritance.