# Printing an object type in ftl

Tags: freemarker

I am new to ftl (freemarker template ). I have a .ftl file and I am trying to acess my own defined type, Foo consisting of just two int variables. For debugging purposes, is there a way I can print the type of the object I am using in ftl. Although I know that it's Foo for sure. But had there been too many user defined types and the name of the model used in ftl were not self suggesting, what would have been my approach?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FreeMarker check the class name of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572548/freemarker-check-the-class-name-of-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Foo` is not a `List`, `Map`, etc., just a plain object, try `${foo.class}`, or even `${foo}` which will call `Foo.toString()`.